# Can I save a matplotlib animation to webm format?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg, webm

I am using this example code as a test case: https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/moviewriter.html

In this code, they use FFMPEG to write the matplotlib animation to an .mp4 video file. Is it possible to write to a .webm format?

But I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: You can use FFMPEG to convert the file see https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/convert-mp4-to-webm/

Comment: Of course, but I want to know if I can use matplotlib to directly output in webm format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `ffmpeg` [compiled](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) with `libvpx` (run `ffmpeg` with no arguments and see if there's a `--enable-libvpx` in the output).

```
FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15, codec='libvpx-vp9') # or libvpx-vp8

[...]

with writer.saving(fig, "writer_test.webm", 100):
    [...]
```