# How can I save an animation from matplotlib as a mp4 video file?

Tags: animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I'm trying to render a animation.ArtistAnimation object into a 24 fps video file in format mp4.

I have search about and I reached [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300010/can-i-save-a-matplotlib-animation-to-webm-format). However, even after compiling ffmpeg I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\trite\OneDrive\Documentos\MusiTex\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
"C:/Users/trite/OneDrive/Documentos/MusiTex/Python/venv/Saving Animation.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trite\OneDrive\Documentos\MusiTex\Python\venv\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 161, in __getitem__
    return self.avail[name]
KeyError: 'ffmpeg'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/trite/OneDrive/Documentos/MusiTex/Python/venv/Saving 
Animation.py", line 20, in <module>
    FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg']
  File "C:\Users\trite\OneDrive\Documentos\MusiTex\Python\venv\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 164, in __getitem__
    'Requested MovieWriter ({}) not available'.format(name))
RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is the problem with?

I would really appreciate if you can help me. Actually, if there is other ways to saving/render this kind of object into a video file (preferably mp4) I will be delighted to hear them.

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you install ffmpeg? If yes, did you put it wherever the script is expecting it? If yes, did ffmpeg actually execute (although it appears not)? If yes, please show the complete log from the ffmpeg command.